# Usings before/after file-scoped namespace

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-10.0

C# 10 gave us file-scoped namespaces. So this:

```cs
using Foo;
using Bar;
namespace Baz {
  // ...
}
```

can be written as:

```cs
using Foo;
using Bar;
namespace Baz;
// ...
```

There are differences between usings before and after a namespace. Does the compiler automatically reorder that to:

```cs
namespace Baz;
using Foo;
using Bar;
// ...
```

If not, is there a `dotnet build` or `msbuild` CLI switch, code analyzer or some other option to enable such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to your `.editorconfig`:

```ini
csharp_using_directive_placement = inside_namespace
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0065

Answer (score 5):

An image says it all:

[image]

As you can see you can select which mode you want in Visual Studio (so it doesn't matter!).

**'Options', 'Text Editor',' 'C#', 'Code Style'.**